# react native 100+ items flatlist very slow performance

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a list just simple text that rendering into flatlist on react native but I am experiencing very very slow performance which makes app unusable.

How can I solve this? My code is:

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'} ... +400]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Here is my suggestions:

**A. Avoid anonymous arrow function on `renderItem` props.**

Move out the `renderItem` function to the outside of render function, so it won't recreate itself each time render function called.

**B. Try add `initialNumToRender` prop on your `FlatList`**

It will define how many items will be rendered for the first time, it could save some resources with lot of data.

**C. Define the `key` prop on your Item Component**

Simply it will avoid re-render on dynamically added/removed items with defined `key` on each item. Make sure it is unique, don't use `index` as the key! You can also using `keyExtractor` as an alternative.

**D. Optional optimization**

Try use `getItemLayout` to skip measurement of dynamic content. Also there is some prop called `maxToRenderPerBatch`, `windowSize` that you can use to limit how many items you will rendered. Refer to the official doc to [VirtualizedList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist) or [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist).

**E. Talk is Cheap, show me the code!**

```js
// render item function, outside from class's `render()`
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (<Text key={item.key}>{item.key}</Text>);

// we set the height of item is fixed
const getItemLayout = (data, index) => (
  {length: ITEM_HEIGHT, offset: ITEM_HEIGHT * index, index}
);

const items = [{ key: 'a' }, { key: 'b'}, ...+400];

function render () => (
  <FlatList
    data={items}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
    initialNumToRender={5}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
    windowSize={10}
  />
);
```

Comment: it says unexpected token

Comment: while `windowSize={10}` it makes it very slow and less performance for me

Comment: Unfortunately, when you are using nested flat lists, react native isn't performant enough for large lists

Answer (score 10):

One of the simple ways to optimize your flatlist is by using **React.memo**. In technical words, it basically does a shallow comparison of your data and check whether they needs to be *re-rendered* or not.

Make a file such as **ListComponent.js** and add the renderItem **JSX** to it, and and it to the renderItem.

```
// ListComponent.js
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const ListComponent = ({ item }) => {
  return  <View ></View>
};

export default memo(ListComponent);
```

Here is your **FlatList**

```
<FlatList
        data={data}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={8}
        windowSize={11}
        initialNumToRender={8}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
               <ListComponent item={item} />
          )}
      />
```

Answer (score 7):

Try out this listview https://github.com/Flipkart/ReactEssentials, it renders far fewer items than FlatList and then recycles them. Should be much faster.

```
npm install --save recyclerlistview
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but for dynamic cant help me any more.

Comment: Check forceNonDeterministicRendering flag

Comment: if you plan to using forceNonDeterministicRendering, better switch back to FlatList

Answer (score 0):

Another optimization would be to provide a `key` using `keyExtractor` prop. It's very important.

Answer (score 0):

I used 'react-native-optimized-flatlist'
and my problem was solved, the only thing to be careful about is that when you use this package, it removes keyExtractor and extraData

Answer (score -2):

You can use react-native-optimized-flatlist. It is the optimized version of Flatlist.

1) Add this package by :

`npm i -S react-native-optimized-flatlist`

OR

`yarn add react-native-optimized-flatlist`

2) Replace `<FlatList/>` by `<OptimizedFlatlist/>`