# React Native Flatlist re-render very slow

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

I have a 250+ product list.
The first time the page loads it is smooth and quick but as I apply a filter in the data and rerender the Flatlist takes a long time to load.
I am really struck past 3 days now and don't know what to do.

Reference:
http://gph.is/2FoBbaO

Please note the time taken after I click the switch.

Code:
There are 2 components.

The list:

```jsx
   toggleVeg = (onlyVeg) => {
      this.setState({ showVegLoader: true });
      const categories = this.state.restaurant.categories;
      const allproducts = [];
      if (onlyVeg) {
        for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < categories[i].products.length; j++) {
            if (categories[i].products[j].is_veg) {
              allproducts.push(categories[i].products[j]);
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < categories[i].products.length; j++) {
            allproducts.push(categories[i].products[j]);
          }
        }
      }
      this.setState({ onlyVeg, allproducts, showVegLoader: false });
  }

  renderRow(product, index) {
    return (
      <FoodItem
        key={index}
        color={this.state.color}
        index={index}
        product={product}
        quantity={this.state.products[product.id].quantity}
        // showNonVeg={!this.state.onlyVeg}
        increment={this.increment}
        decrement={this.decrement}
        incrementModal={this.incrementModal}
        decrementModal={this.decrementModal}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
      <FlatList
            style={{ padding: 0 }}
            data={this.state.allproducts}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderRow(item, index)}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            extraData={this.state}
            removeClippedSubviews
          />
      );
    }
```

The FoodItem component:

```jsx
      render() {
    const { index, product, quantity, color } = this.props;
    let image = veg;
    if (product.is_veg !== 1) {
      image = nonveg;
    }
    // let opacity = 1;
    // let height = 'auto';
    // let width = 'auto';
    // if (!showNonVeg && product.is_veg !== 1) {
    //   opacity = 0;
    //   height = 0;
    //   width = 0;
    // }

    return (
      <View key={index}>
        <Row style={{ flex: 1, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, paddingBottom: 5 }}>
          <Left
            style={{ flex: 0.08,
              marginTop: 3,
              alignItems: 'flex-start',
              alignSelf: 'flex-start',
              justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}
          >
            <Image
              style={{ width: 16, height: 16 }}
              source={image}
            />
          </Left>
          <Body
            style={{ flex: 0.62 }}
          >
            <Row
              style={{ flex: 1,
                padding: 0,
                alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                alignItems: 'center' }}
            >
              <Subtitle
                style={{ fontSize: 14,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
                  fontWeight: '500' }}
              >
                {product.name}
              </Subtitle>
            </Row>
            <Row
              style={{ flex: 1,
                padding: 0,
                alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                alignItems: 'center' }}
            >
              <Caption>
                {constants.CURRENCY} {product.variants[0].price.toFixed(2)}
              </Caption>
            </Row>
          </Body>
          <Right style={{ flex: 0.3 }}>
            {uiQuantity}
          </Right>
        </Row>
        <Subtitle
          style={{ paddingLeft: 25,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
            fontWeight: '400',
            fontSize: 12
          }}
        >
          {product.description}
        </Subtitle>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

P.S. removed some code that was irrelevant.

Comment: is FoodItem a pure component

Comment: Yes.
export default class FoodItem extends React.PureComponent

Comment: so this problem still unsolved? now it's Jan-21,  10 day passed

Comment: Haven't found any solution yet.
Though I did use another list: https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview/
Seems to be fast enough. Still implementing, will post a solution if it is good enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react native 100+ items flatlist very slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384773/react-native-100-items-flatlist-very-slow-performance)

Answer (score 1):

1) Does function `toggleVeg` works fast enough ? (may be problem in it)

2) Do you have `id` for products ? If yes, use them in `keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}` to avoid re-render of the same products items

Comment: 1) toggleVeg takes 3 milliseconds to return.
2) Yes. Did that still same time. :(