# Flatlist is making my app very slow

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I need to render about 1000 rows with `Flatlist`. Unfortunately, after rendering a few ones without problems, my app begins to be very slow and freezing so that it become totally impossible to manipulate. I'm looking for a solution to use instead of `Flatlist` which showed its limit. I need a module that can handle hundreds of rows without any problem.

Can someone provide me some advices ?

```
   <FlatList

   data={this.state.data}
    onEndReached={this.props.onEndReached}
    initialNumToRender={5}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.objectID}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
  />
```

Comment: Does the application render the 1000 rows instantly to view, or for example 50 at beginning and when scrolling to bottom of page it renders another 50 etc...?

Comment: I want to be able to do both. In fact, even when i load the items progressively, the flatlist slow down my app in any case.

Comment: can you show code of the Flatlist

Comment: yes of course..

Comment: whats your threshold? Also, please do not load 1k rows altogether. This is a bridged version of the table, so there will be performance overheads. I suggest making a native version of it then using it. People claim it to be a lot faster

Comment: Although programmatically you can do, in mobile development render about 1000 rows is not a good practice, the view can become saturated specially in mobiles that doesn't have so much RAM. In case to do that, try to render them bit a bit fo example, 50 per 50, this should make the app go faster.

Comment: (even though it isnt ideal) I tried rendering 5000 items with reasonable speed/performance (they still loading, but the performance is okay). Can you show the whole class component please.

Comment: **render about 1000 rows with Flatlist, really?** Never do that in any case, no one need that and make app slow, jus 20 rows is good, and load more when user scrolldown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react native 100+ items flatlist very slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384773/react-native-100-items-flatlist-very-slow-performance)

Answer (score 0):

- Implement **shouldComponentUpdate** or use the **[PureComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)** to reduce unnecessary re-rendering.
- Make sure FlatList is not a child of ScrollView.

**OR**

You can try other third party plugins:

- [react-native-optimized-flatlist](https://github.com/stoffern/react-native-optimized-flatlist)
- [react-native-ultimate-listview](https://github.com/gameboyVito/react-native-ultimate-listview)