# When there is a large list , flat list is laggy and sometimes crashing app in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Please help me. When there is a large list, flat list is laggy and sometimes crashing app in react native .

I have tried Optimized list: it is not showing images, and i have tried react-native large list. Nothing is working.

This is the code:

```
 {loading == false && (
                      <FlatList
                        data={this.state.data}
                        numColumns="2"
                        renderItem={({ item }) => <ExampleComponent url= 
                        {item.media} />}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.itemurl}
                        windowSize={15}
                        onEndReachedThreshold={1}
                        onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
                        removeClippedSubviews={true}
                        maxToRenderPerBatch={10}

                      />
                    )}
```

This is component class

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image ,TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";
export default class ExampleComponent extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.imageContainer}>
      <View >
        <FastImage
          source={{
            uri:this.props.url
          }}
          style={styles.imageStyle}
        />
      </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#dedede",
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 5
  },
  imageStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: 100,
    borderTopLeftRadius:5,
    borderTopRightRadius:5
  },

});
```

[And im getting this message in console when rows are more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sFIl.png)

This is handle load more function

```
handleLoadMore = () => {
console.log("Called");

if (this.state.next != 0) {
  const u =
    "https://url&q=" +
    this.props.navigation.state.params.data +
    "&pos=" +
    this.state.next;
  fetch(u, {
    method: "GET"
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        data: [...this.state.data, ...response.results],
        next: response.next
      });
    });
}
```

}

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"dt":1098,"prevDt":684,"contentLength":6832}

Comment: try to remove initialNumToRender and adjust windowSize for your use case. Also, you can try legacyImplementation={true} and play around

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will try it nowitself

Comment: How large is large? How many items are you rendering? Flatlist is the already optimised list for React Native. Please add the code for ExampleComponent as well.

Comment: <TouchableOpacity style={styles.imageContainer}>
      <View >
        <FastImage
          source={{
            uri:this.props.url
          }}
          style={styles.imageStyle}
        />
      </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>   Large in the sense number of items after 100 + rows its laggy and crashes

Comment: And also when i wrap flat list in a scroll view , onendreached is called infinite times and app crashes and when i remove scroll view onendreached is called correctly

Comment: You shouldn't wrap a flatlist in a scrollview, as it is already an implementation of it. Have a read at [the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)

Comment: @TJagadishGupta please add the code to your question. Edit the question and add all the relevant code. Please add all the ExampleComponent class or const code to your question.

Comment: Thats absolutely correct but if i did not wrap it in scroll view enitre page is not scrolling , sorry im new to react native @c-chavez

Comment: @c-chavez i have updated the question , please help me i have been trying to resolve since three days

Comment: @TJagadishGupta don't worry we will get to your problem, but we need more information. Please add the handleLoadMore function code to your question. Also, if you want to add error messages to your question don't use images, they might get broken over time or hard to read in some devices. Please add the error message as text to your question.

Comment: @c-chavez Thank you very much , i have pasted handleLoadMore method and also updated the console  message

Comment: @TJagadishGupta are you wrapping the FlatList in something special? or is it just a view?

Comment: I'm wrapping flatlist in a view and I have tried all your points its working in some phones when I tried in mi phone the app is crashing , can you give me an example code to implement flatlist correctly @c-chavez

Comment: @TJagadishGupta Which phone do you have? in which phones does it work? does it crash when it opens the flatlist or is it after you get to a certain part of your list?

Comment: In pure android phones it works like one plus , Google , but in xaiomi Samsung crashes while scrolling more data

Comment: @c-chavez thanks man you are my hero recycler view is working like a charm thank you very much , oh man since 3 days I've been trying thank you very much

Comment: @TJagadishGupta You are welcome. Flatlist is tough to handle for large lists and some approaches that I mentioned worked in some cases for me so it all depends on your situation.

Comment: @c-chavez yes you are right , thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react native 100+ items flatlist very slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384773/react-native-100-items-flatlist-very-slow-performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the performance of the Flatlist depends on each implementation, you can follow these suggestions to help you in your case.

Try combinations of these approaches:

- Enable or disable legacyImplementation
- Enable or disable disableVirtualization
- Increase or decrease the value of onEndReachedThreshold
- Increase or decrease the value of windowSize
- Increase or decrease the value of maxToRenderPerBatch
- Implement shouldComponentUpdate
- Remove the constructor from ExampleComponent
- Enable removeClippedSubviews only for Android
- Use a simpler keyExtractor, a number if possible.

Actually [from the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#keyextractor):

> The default extractor checks item.key, then falls back to using the
>   index, like React does.

**Also**

Check in your render method how many items are being loaded and rendered in both ExampleComponent and your component that uses the FlatList.

**Alternatively**

Try using [RecyclerListview](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) component.

**Further reading**

- [Improve render performance for Flatlist](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips)
- [FlatList Scroll performance is laggy after 30+ rows](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13413)

Comment: Flatlist natively is using RecyclerListView in android.

Comment: @MatinZD I was trying to find this in the official repository but didn't find anything related, or probably at the time of my answer it wasn't used by `Flatlist`. If you can share with us where you saw this, we could add it to the answer to make it more complete, for Android devs, keeping in mind that it could be an alternative for IOS devs.