# performance issues with React-Native flatlist with 100+ list items

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to use RN flatlist to show a large list of contact names (100+ items). I keep getting the following warning:

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make
>   sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React
>   performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate,
>   etc.

Certain animated UI items get very sluggish whenever the list has more than 50 items in it, however the sluggishness gets a lot better once I scroll all the way down to the bottom of the list

I grab all the contacts in one go and store them in an array in a redux store. I have tried using props like initialNumToRender but cant seem to improve performance. Is there anything I can do to improve my list? I have never used RN FlatList before so any tips would be appreciated

Here is my list related code:

```
renderRow = ({item}) => {

 return (
  <ListItem
   title={item.firstName}
   chevronColor={colors.tertiary}
  />
 )
}


  <FlatList
   data={this.props.contacts}
   renderItem={this.renderRow}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
   initialNumToRender={10}
   removeClippedSubviews={true}
  />
```

`this.props.contacts` is the array of contact objects in the redux store

Comment: can you show the full implementation ! i think that is something relevant to your code  implementation!

Comment: you should see if you have the INFAMOUS QOUTE FOLLOWED "convert your components to PureComponents"

Comment: Maybe you can use this https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview

Comment: I will try implementing the recyclerlistview component. Documentation is lacking but ill try and get it working. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react native 100+ items flatlist very slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384773/react-native-100-items-flatlist-very-slow-performance)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up implementing [recyclerlistview](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) and followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32ZM72CKtTE) which explained how to get it working since the documentation is lacking. Its working miles better than flat list did. Very fast and smooth.

Comment: is it worthy? bcoz I'm in the deadline and want to refactor all flatList inside my app? it'll take a long time?

Comment: I have followed tutorial you provides and used it but it is taking too much time for rendering, is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these code implementations.
For VIEWABILITY_CONFIG follow this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#viewabilityconfig)

```
const VIEWABILITY_CONFIG - {
  minimumViewTime: 300,
  viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100,
  waitForInteraction
}
const yourItemHeight = 108;
class yourClass extends React.PureComponent
...

_getItemLayout(data, index) {
return { lenght: yourItemHeight, offset: yourItemHeight * index, index }
}
 <FlatList
   data={this.props.contacts}
   renderItem={this.renderRow}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
   getItemLayout: {this._getItemLayout}
   initialNumToRender={10} // Vary According to your screen size take a lumsum according to your item height
   removeClippedSubviews={true}
   viewabilityConfig={VIEWABILITY_CONFIG}
  />
```