# Low Scroll Performance and Blank Problem in React Native Flatlist

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I am using flatlist for rendering a long list of items with different heights and when I scroll it fast, I see blank space and it doesn't work well. I tried **react-native-big-list** and **react-native-largelist** and **recyclerlistview**. These packages don't have that problems but they require a static height for items so I can not use them.

Comment: Can find some insights here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384773/react-native-100-items-flatlist-very-slow-performance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.